# How do I refresh contents of an array from a file in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, macos

I'm building a menu app in Swift to read the latest line from a log file. I can load the log into an array, but need to refresh it, preferably automatically. How do I get it to refresh my array? And then how do I trigger that to happen automatically?

The app is a menu item. When you click it, a window appears with a textfield showing the last entry in the `logList` array. The `logList.init` function sits in the `viewDidLoad` function. I tried moving that to `viewWillLoad` and no change. I've tried declaring it with the `.init` function just in the class, and then re-doing it in the `viewDidLoad` with a `didset` in the original declaration that updates the textfield. Still only loads on first open.

The variable declaration:

```
public var logList = LogLine.init(logLocationSTRING: " ") {
        didSet{
            latestLog = logList.logLines[(logList.logLines.count)-2]
            logLabel.stringValue = latestLog ?? "No logs found."
        }
    }
```

The initialization:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        logList = LogLine.init(logLocationSTRING: "file:///some/log/file.log")
    }
```

The struct takes the string value of the file URL and converts it to a usable URL, loads the contents of the log into a variable, then converts those contents into an array with each line as its own item.

I expect after closing the window and re-opening it, that it should re-call the .init function and update the contents of the `logList` variable, but it doesn't. The variable never changes unless I quit my app and re-open it.

Comment: `viewDidLoad()` and `viewWillLoad()` are only called on the first load of the view. Unless you dismiss it and present it again they won’t be called. Move your declaration to another lifecycle method, maybe `viewWillAppear()` which is called every time the view will appear on the main window.

Comment: @GaloTorresSevilla: That is exactly what my problem was. I changed it to `viewWillAppear()` and it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`viewDidLoad` is called only once unless you explicitly deallocate the view controller after closing the window.

There are at least 3 options:

1. Put the code in `viewWillAppear`.
2. Extend `NSStatusBarButton`, override `mouseDown` and load the data there.
3. Adopt `NSMenuDelegate`, connect the menu and load the data in `menuWillOpen`.

Comment: If I adopt the `NSMenuDelegate`, does that offer other functionality, like the ability to have it checking my `file.log` for other things when the window isn't open? The next step is to change the menu icon color if there's a new log within `x minutes`.

Comment: As the view controller is alive you can run a timer independent of the status of the window.

Comment: I guess I'm thinking while the controller is closed. The outcome would be that the icon is black most of the time, but when a log is added, it turns green for 2 minutes, then goes back to black.

Comment: Rather than polling the path I would add an observer which notifies when the log file is being modified. This can be accomplished with DispatchSourceFileSystemObject

Comment: I've been looking for info on DispatchSourceFileSystemObject, and I can't find anything helpful. I'm still pretty new to coding so Apple's documentation is still a foreign language. Do you have any good resources you can suggest? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're aiming for `viewWillAppear` rather than `viewDidLoad`.

I'm not sure I understand the exact flow you describe, but `viewDidLoad` only happens once during the lifecycle of a view controller, so it may be that moving your `logList` code into `viewWillAppear` will do the trick.

For more information, please see "Handling View-Related Notifications" in [Apple's UIViewController documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller)

Comment: That's exactly what it was. I was getting `viewWillLoad()` and `viewWillAppear()` mixed up.